# Замена слов в рандомном порядке в Memo

Tags: delphi

Идея такова:

1. В `Memo1.Text` находится простой текст.
2. В `Memo2.Text` находятся слова для рандомной замены в тексте `Memo1`. К примеру:

   ```
    Слово #1|Замена1|Замена2|Замена3
    Слово №2|Замена1|Замена2|Замена3
    Слово №3|Замена1|Замена2|Замена3
   ```
3. То есть в `Memo1` расположен сам текст, а в `Memo2` словарь синонимов, слов и варианты их замены.
4. При нажатии на кнопку в `Memo1` идет замена слов на синонимы из `Memo2`.

Вопрос: Где в коде у меня ошибка ?  Поскольку у меня получается, что замена идет только первых слов, что в тексте (строках) `Memo1`, а должна быть замена по всей строке.

Вот мой код и может его можно как упростить?

```
Var
  SynArr: Array of Array of String;
  SynList: TStringList;
  i, j, m: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(SynArr, 0);
  SynList := TStringList.Create;
  // Тут идет подключение Слов и к ним синонимов в Memo2
  Memo2.Lines[i] := StringReplace(WrapText(Memo2.Lines[i], #13#10, ['|'], 1),
    '|', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
  SetLength(SynArr, Length(SynArr) + 1);
  SetLength(SynArr[High(SynArr)], Memo2.Lines.Count);
   // Обработка в цикле синонимов
  for i := 0 to Memo2.Lines.Count - 1 do
    SynArr[High(SynArr), i] := Memo2.Lines.Strings[i];
  SynList.Free;

  // Замена слов на синонимы в Memo1
  for i := 0 to High(SynArr) do
    for j := 0 to High(SynArr[i]) do
      for m := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do
        Memo1.Lines[m] := StringReplace(Memo1.Lines[m], SynArr[i, j],
          SynArr[i, Random(High(SynArr[i])) + 1], []);

end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну давайте попробуем так:

- разбиваем каждую строку первого списка на список слов по пробелам и запятым (commatext)
- проверяем, не содержится ли слово в словаре
- если да - то заменяем его на один из синонимов, выбирая индекс синонима случайно
- после обработки всех слов строки собираем их обратно (тот же commatext в обратном направлении)
- записываем измененную строку назад в список

Comment: Пока что у меня безуспешные попытки. А commatext это что ?

Comment: А в хелпе разве нет commatext ?

Comment: Есть, буду пробовать. Но пока что идея не пришла как правильно сделать. Спасибо.